# where does address of variables stored in a memory?

Tags: c, memory

whenever we need to find the address of the variable we use below syntax in C and it prints a address of the variable. what i am trying to understand is the address that returned is actual physical memory location or compiler throwing a some random number. if it is either physical or random, where did it get those number or where it has to be stored in memory. actually does address of the memory location takes space in the memory?

```
int a = 10;
printf("ADDRESS:%d",&a);
```

ADDRESS: 2234xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

This location is from the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), which is allocated to your program. In other words, this is from the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), which your OS maps to a physical memory, as and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of system you've got.

- Low-end systems such as microcontroller applications often only supports physical addresses.
- Mid-range CPUs often come with a MMU (memory mapping unit) which allows so-called virtual memory to be placed on top of the physical memory. Meaning that a certain part of the code could be working from address 0 to x, though in reality those virtual addresses are just aliases for physical ones.
- High-end systems like PC typically only allows virtual memory access and denies applications direct access to physical memory. They often also use [Address space layout randomization (ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to produce random address layouts for certain kinds of memory, in order to prevent hacks that exploit hard-coded addresses.

In either case, the actual address itself does not take up space in memory.

Higher abstraction layer concepts such as file systems may however store addresses in look-up tables etc and then they will take up memory.

Answer (score 0):

> … is the address that returned is actual physical memory location or compiler throwing a some random number

In general-purpose operating systems, the addresses in your C program are virtual memory addresses.<sup>1</sup>

> if it is either physical or random, where did it get those number or where it has to be stored in memory.

The software that loads your program into memory makes the final decisions about what addresses are used<sup>2</sup>, and it may inform your program about those addresses in various ways, including:

- It may put the start addresses of certain parts of the program in designated processor registers. For example, the start address of the read-only data of your program might be put in R17, and then your program would use R17 as a base address for accessing that data.
- It may “fix up” addresses built into your program’s instructions and data. The program’s executable file may contain information about places in your program’s instructions or data that need to be updated when the virtual addresses are decided. After the instructions and data are loaded into memory, the loader will use the information in the file to find those places and update them.
- With position-independent code, the program counter itself (a register in the processor that contains the address of the instruction the processor is currently executing or about to execute) provides address information.

So, when your program wants to evaluate `&x`, it may take the offset of `x` from the start of the section it is in (and that offset is built into the program by the compiler and possibly updated by the linker) and adds it to the base address of that section. The resulting sum is the address of `x`.

> actually does address of the memory location takes space in the memory?

The C standard does not require the program to use any memory for the address of `x`, `&x`. The result of `&x` is a value, like the result of `3*x`. The only thing the compiler has to do with a value is ensure it gets used for whatever further expression it is used in. It is not required to store it in memory. However, if the program is dealing with many values in a piece of code, so there are not enough processor registers to hold them all, the compiler may choose to store values in memory temporarily.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Virtual memory is a conceptual or “imaginary” address space. Your program can execute with virtual addresses because the hardware automatically translates virtual addresses to physical addresses while it is executing the program. The operating system creates a map that tells the hardware how to translate virtual addresses to physical addresses. (The map may also tell the hardware certain virtual memory is not actually in physical memory at the moment. In this case, the hardware interrupts the program and starts an operating system routine which deals with the issue. That routine arranges for the needed data to be loaded into memory and then updates the virtual memory map to indicate that.)

<sup>2</sup> There is usually a general scheme for how parts of the program are laid out in memory, such as starting the instructions in one area and setting up space for stack in another area. In modern systems, some randomness is intentionally added to the addresses to foil malicious people trying to take advantage of bugs in programs.